# In nginx for proxy_cache_path directive max_size does it relate to size of the folder

Tags: nginx

Below is my proxy_cache_path settings. The setting for max_size is 10GB. when I checked to folder size it is 41GB. I noticed that when some of the cache is getting deleted before 7day cache-control: max-age=2592000. Could it be because the folder size if 41GB. Does max_size relate to size of the folder?

proxy_cache_path /var/cache/nginx/questionsAndAnswers levels=2:2:2 keys_zone=questionsAndAnswers:125m inactive=7d max_size=10g;